# In Bokeh Python, LabelSet annotation does not work well if the x and y axes contain alphabet letters

Tags: python, annotations, bokeh

Maybe the title is not clear, so let me explain my question. I tried LabelSet with all numbers at the x and y axes, it works perfectly. However, when I changed to use all Alphabet letters such as A, A+, B, etc, the LabelSet does not understand and put all annotations on the top left (I attached the image about the error below.)

I tried to debug and find out the problem is at labels = LabelSet(x = 'average_grades', y = 'exam_grades'). If I change x = integer, and y = integer, it works. Please help me to fix it since I want to apply LabelSet in many cases, not only with numbers.

```
#importing libraries
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.annotations import LabelSet, Label
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.layouts import layout

#create columndatasource
source=ColumnDataSource(dict(average_grades=["B+","A","D-"],
                              exam_grades=["A+","C","D"],
                              student_names=["Stephan","Helder","Riazudidn"]))

#create the figure

grade1 = ["F","D-","D","D+","C-","C","C+","B-","B","B+","A-","A","A+"]
grade2 = ["F","D-","D","D+","C-","C","C+","B-","B","B+","A-","A","A+"]

f = figure(x_range= grade1,
           y_range= grade2)
f.plot_width = 1100
f.plot_height =  650

#add labels for glyphs
labels=LabelSet(x='average_grades',y='exam_grades',
                text="student_names",
                x_offset=20, y_offset=20,
                text_color = 'red', source=source, level = 'glyph',
                render_mode = "css", text_font_size = "20pt")
f.add_layout(labels)

description = Label(x = 4, y = 2, text="Hello World", render_mode = "css")
f.add_layout(description)

#create glyphs
f.circle(x="average_grades", y="exam_grades", source=source, size=8)

#create function
def update_labels(attr,old,new):
    labels.text=select.value
#     #labels.text = getattr(select, attr)

#create select widget
options=[("average_grades","Average Grades"),("exam_grades","Exam Grades"),("student_names","Student Names")]
select=Select(title="Attribute",options=options)
select.on_change("value",update_labels)

# #create layout and add to curdoc
lay_out=layout([[select]])
curdoc().add_root(f)
curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please, *always* provide relevant version information with *every* question.

This just seems like a bug. I can see the problem on latest Bokeh version 2.2.1 however if I try a 2.3 development version, the problem has gone away. So evidently this was fixed at some point recently, though perhaps inadvertently. Please file a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) so that we can make sure any fix is intentional and preserved under test. The solution is to wait for the next release 2.3 (or a 2.2.2 if one is made).

In the mean time, the only suggestion I can offer is to use integer coordinates in stead of categorical (string) coordinates, then use [fixed ticker values](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#fixedticker) with tick label overrides:

```
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {1: "A", 2, "B", ...}
```

to make it "look the same".